# MySQL and PHP search for similar words in result

Tags: php, mysql

i have a searchbox in which user can give input Date.This input text will be searched in database and results are retrieved through the syntax..

There are 3 search box Order Name, Order No & Date i just want for Date search only.

```
$sno = 1;
$userID = $_SESSION["loginID"];

if(isset($_REQUEST["Submit2"]) || isset($_REQUEST["Submit22"]) || isset($_REQUEST["Submit222"]))
{
    $dName = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["dName"]);
    $qNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["qNumber"]);
    $qDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["qDate"]);

    if ($qDate!="") {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE oDate = '".$qDate."' AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC";
    }elseif ($qNumber!="") {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderNo LIKE '%".$qNumber."%' AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC";
    }elseif ($dName!="") {
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE designName = '".$dName."' AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC";
    }

}else{
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE orderType='order' AND userID = '".$userID."' ORDER BY  SNo  DESC";
}
$SQLRes=mysql_query($SQL);
```

in the datebase any order date value like this 2017-08-24 01:08:27
so when i type same input in box 2017-08-24 01:08:27 then its working. i want if input in search box 2017 OR 2017-08 so it will search similar and i can get data in result with month or year its not working for similar input.

Comment: While this won't fix your problem, please note the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: dear i am using this on php 5.3.0 i just need a correct query for this requirement

Comment: PHP 5.3 was [**obsoleted**](http://php.net/eol.php) in August 2014 (over three years ago). I'd *strongly* recommend upgrading. PHP 5.3.0 **alone** has [**97 security vulnerabilities**](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-82589/PHP-PHP-5.3.0.html) (many of them critical). Not only could someone `DROP` your table, but they could even execute arbitrary code remotely. You don't 'just' need the correct query; your security is a **far** bigger concern.

Comment: i understand and Thank you. can you please guide $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE oDate = '".$qDate."' AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC"; how it will search with similar input ?

Answer (score 0):

The normative criteria for a DATETIME range

to match "2008" or "2008-" would be

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.odate >= '2008-01-01'
  AND t.odate <  '2008-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

to match "2008-03"

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.odate >= '2008-03-01'
  AND t.odate <  '2008-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

to match "2008-04-14"

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND t.odate >= '2008-04-14'
  AND t.odate <  '2008-04-14' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

With these forms, MySQL can make effective use of a range scan on an appropriate index.

---

If we want sluggish performance, we can force MySQL to evaluate a function on *every* row in the table and doing a string comparison with a light dimming query like this:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND DATE_FORMAT(t.odate,'%Y-%-m-%d %T') LIKE CONCAT( '2008' ,'%')
```

or

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND DATE_FORMAT(t.odate,'%Y-%-m-%d %T') LIKE CONCAT( '2008-04-14' ,'%')
```

(This is assuming that `odate` is defined as DATETIME datatype, not character type.)

---

The PHP `mysql_` interface functions are deprecated (for a lont time), and finally removed in the most recent versions of PHP.

New development should use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Also, seems like a lot of repeated code.  Seems like the query is always going to start the same way; what changes is the conditions that get tacked on to the `WHERE` clause and the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
  $SQL = "SELECT t.* FROM orders t WHERE 1=1" ;

  if( somecond ) {
      $SQL .= " AND t.designname = ?";
  }
  if( someothercond ) {
      $SQL .= " AND t.orderNo LIKE CONCAT('%', ? ,'%')";
  }

  if ( somethingelse ) { 
      $SQL .= " ORDER BY t.orderNum DESC";
  }
  else {
      $SQL .= " ORDER BY t.sNo DESC";
  }

  // for debugging, display the generated SQL
  //var_dump($SQL);

  $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
  if ( somecond ) {
     $sth->bindValue($dname);
  }
  if ( someothercond ) {
     $sth->bindValue($qNumber);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Spencer Dear. can you please update this query with your suggestion i am confused $SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE oDate = '".$qDate."' AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC";

Answer (score 0):

You should be using mysql functions `year()` and `month()` so your date search query should look like :

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (year(oDate ) = year('".$qDate."') 
            OR (year(oDate ) = year('".$qDate."') AND month(oDate ) = month('".$qDate."')) )
            AND orderType='Order' ORDER BY  orderNum DESC";
```

Comment: Hi shivgre Thank you its not working, in database search is TIMESTAMP type SQL

Comment: It should work with timestamp date as well. As long as the date is in mysql timestamp format it should work. Try this query to verify `SELECT YEAR('2017-05-06 23:12:22'); ` which should return 2017.

Comment: in myphpadmin i run this query SELECT YEAR('2017-05-06 23:12:22'); Result 2017 but your code update in php search not working

Comment: the code I sent should search either by `year` or by `year and month` of `$qDate` so if the year matches any `oDate` year from `$qDate` it should return those rows as well as rows containing same year and month in `oDate`

Comment: after update your code when in search box input 2017 no result and when i put a input which exist in database 2017-09-13 00:09:13 then in result it is showing All the table result other customer records in another account

Comment: `$qDate` should be either a valid mysql format date or timestamp. Yes it will fetch all orders from same year or (year & month) i.e. its giving results from year + year & month combination. To return orders from a specific customer you just need to add another `AND` condition with customerId for that particular customer. You now have the logic which you can modify as per your requirements :)

Comment: when input year and month its not showing the result eg 2017-10 no result

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a valid mysql format date i.e. `YYY-MM-DD` format for the `$qDate` search input field.

Comment: 2017-09-23 no result

Comment: Does your order table contain rows with year 2017 and month 9?, can you share a db dump of one row?

Comment: 2017-09-23 its exist in db table order  thats why i am searching and no result

Comment: Try running the query in phpmyadmin with hardcoded $qDate field and try executing query part by part and debug and see what portion is not returning valid results and thus modify it accordingly. Its hard to tell anything further without seeing your database data.

Comment: i have another php page and search customer email box when i put any similar its working the code is $SQL = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE  allow = 'y' and email1 LIKE '%".$emailee."%' order by ID desc";

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that. I tried to help with what I could. If my answer helped you then please upvote and mark it as answered.